# Excel - Text to columns prompt before opening csv file

Tags: excel

I have a number of CSV files that I open with Excel, however, when I open the CSV files I do not get the Text to Columns prompt, how do I get this to prompt before I open the csv file?

The leading zeros from cell are being removed automatically by Excel, even if I try the Text to Columns after I have open the CSV files, the leading zeros are still not appearing. I assume other formatting is taking place.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Have you opened the CSV in a text editor to confirm the original data has leading zeros?

Comment: Hi - Yes, I have confirm the data contains leading zeros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do not open the csv's by double-clicking.**

First open Excel and then use the Data Import Wizard:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much. Cheers.